# how to create sql-insert statement for each element/attribute from a XML-File

Tags: sql, xml, insert, element

I've got an xml file like this (in fact its much larger) and I have to create an SQLinsert statement for each element and attribute.

If possible I should include in each statement also the ancestor nodes and a `sort_no` which should automatically counted up,
e.g

```
insert into table (name, ancestor, sort_no) 
values ('ctgyID','chrgCpt', 1)
```

*How can this be achieved?*

```
<M001>  
    <chrgGp>
        <chrgCpt>
            <ctgyID/>
            <ctgy/>
            <ctgyName/>
            <ctgyAmt ccy=""/>
            <chrgUid/>
            <chrgDesc/>
        </chrgCpt>
    </chrgGp>
    <taxAnalysis>
        <auTax>
            <auStartDt/>
            <auEndDt/>
            <auInt ccy=""/>
            <auIntTax ccy=""/>
            <auUnfrkDiv ccy=""/>
            <auDivTax ccy=""/>
            <auFrkDiv ccy=""/>
            <auImpCrdts ccy=""/>
            <auDistrTaxFree ccy=""/>
            <auDistrTaxDfrd ccy=""/>
            <auDistrOthr ccy=""/>
            <auDistrTax ccy=""/>
            <auDistrExp ccy=""/>
            <auForGr ccy=""/>
            <auForExp ccy=""/>
            <auForTaxCr ccy=""/>
            <auCapGnIndx ccy=""/>
            <auCapGnDisc ccy=""/>
            <auCapGnOthr ccy=""/>
            <auCapDistr ccy=""/>
            <auCGTConc ccy=""/>
        </auTax>
    </taxAnalysis>
    <log>
        <lvl/>
        <dtTm/>
        <code/>
        <msg/>
    </log>
</M001>
```

Comment: Could you specify which RBDMS you are using and give an example of what this input data would look like once it has been inserted?

Comment: Can any of those XML elements be *repeated* in your XML file?

Comment: it's for an oracle database, xml elements can occur multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

IF this is for **SQL Server**, then you could try something like this:

```
DECLARE @XmlText XML = '.....your XML here .....'

SELECT
    ctgyID = @XmlText.value('(/M001/chrgGp/chrgCpt/ctgyID)[1]', 'varchar(20)'),
    auStartDt = XC.value('(auStartDt)[1]', 'varchar(100)'),
    auEndDt = XC.value('(auEndDt)[1]', 'varchar(100)'),
    auInt = XC.value('(auInt/@ccy)[1]', 'varchar(100)'),
    auIntTax = XC.value('(auIntTax/@ccy)[1]', 'varchar(100)'),
    auUnfrkDiv = XC.value('(auUnfrkDiv)[1]', 'varchar(100)'),
    auDivTax = XC.value('(auDivTax)[1]', 'varchar(100)'),
    auFrkDiv = XC.value('(auFrkDiv)[1]', 'varchar(100)'),
    auImpCrdts = XC.value('(auImpCrdts/@ccy)[1]', 'varchar(100)'),
    auDistrTaxFree = XC.value('(auDistrTaxFree/@ccy)[1]', 'varchar(100)'),
    auDistrTaxDfrd = XC.value('(auDistrTaxDfrd/@ccy)[1]', 'varchar(100)'),
    auDistrOthr = XC.value('(auDistrOthr/@ccy)[1]', 'varchar(100)'),
    .... AND so on ......
FROM 
    @XmlText.nodes('/M001/taxAnalysis/auTax') AS XT(XC)
```

When you know what datatypes you have, you could also include those as the second parameter for every `.value()` call - since you didn't provide values (just empty XML elements), I couldn't really know what those datatypes would be.

With this approach, you will get the values from *each* `<taxAnalysis> / <auTax>` node in your document, together with the `ctgyID` value from the "header"

Comment: thank you, thinking about it, the easier way is to write a little vba script which does this for me. in fact it's not really a xml transformation.